# How to resolve HA: px ≠ py?

Tags: r, sample

I have two samples:

```
allprogrammers <- subset(df, job == "programmer")
sampleprogrammers <- sample(1:523, 50, replace=FALSE)
allprogrammers_sample = allprogrammers[sampleprogrammers]
```

and

```
allanalysts <- subset(df, job == "analysts")
sampleanalysts <- sample(1:482, 50, replace=FALSE)
allanalysts_sample = allanalysts[sampleanalysts]
```

I need to proof that **HA: px ≠ py** (so **allprogrammers ≠ allanalysts**) with **2%**.

All the info the teacher gave us before starting to work at home is this, but I really don't understand how to use this to resolve the problem.

```
Cas de deux populations
Exemple 9.5
H0: px=py contre HA: px != py
prop.test(x = c(54, 108), n = c(300, 450), alternative="two.sided", conf.level=0.90)
```

Comment: This seems like more a statistics question than a programming question. I would recommend asking at stats.stackexchange instead of here. Perhaps provide a small sample of what is in `df`---that is, what are the ways that programmers or analysts may be the same or different. or a hypothesis test.

Comment: From a programming point of view, the change I would recommend so far is to make `sampleprogrammers` sample from `1:nrow(allprogrammers)` instead of `1:523`... assuming that's where your `523` came from. (And similarly for analysts).

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot!
My table looks like this, with 2000 employees:

```
Status Job Hours Salary
Permanent Programmer 40 45k
Permanent Analyst 35 50k
Temporary Programmer 35 47k
Permanent Programmer 40 47k
Temporary Technician 35 50k
```

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could mention the topics you are covering in class. Presumably your teacher has a method in mind for you to use on this problem, but methods might be very different if they are based on, e.g., monte carlo sampling, a probability computation, or a hypothesis test. (Sorry, edited my first comment but the bit about hypothesis test got stuck up there)

Comment: Your data surprises me - from you description I thought there would be names or ID numbers and the idea would be to infer, from the sample, whether some people who are analysts are not programmers, or vice versa. But your data shows nothing of the type. What are `px` and `py`? Are you comparing average salary, or permanant vs temporary status, or mean hours? Something else?

Comment: Its a basic statistic course
We learn the standard deviation, the mean, poisson, and the basic things
But he really wanted us to try R and he gave us a big work with this... He did not gave us much information about this program so it's really hard to me to understand ahhaha

The question is this:
Take a simple random sample of size nx = 50 from all the programmers in the population using the "sample" function of R.
Same with analysts
From the two samples drawn, test the alternative hypothesis HA: ≠, using a significance level α = 2%.

Comment: Well, I think you need to ask your instructor for more detail. You probably want a t-test, based on the salary of your samples, but I can't tell you what only your instructor knows.